# MITM Traffic forwarding not working on Kali

Tags: man-in-the-middle

I'm doing a ARP Spoofing MITM attack like this:

```
arpspoof -i wlan0 -t 192.168.1.112 192.168.1.1 -r
```

And I can see the traffic from the target (`192.168.1.112`) showing up in the sniffer, but the target is never getting any responses back, leading to a DoS for the target instead of a subtle sniffing attack.

I have ip forwarding turned on:

```
root@kali:~/network-hacking-scripts# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

And I have no firewall rules on:

```
root@kali:~/network-hacking-scripts# iptables-save
root@kali:~/network-hacking-scripts#
```

I'm running on the latest version of Kali Linux (2016.1). It's running in VirtualBox inside an OS X host. I'm using a `TP-LINK TL-WN722N` external wireless adapter for Kali.

Any thoughts on why the traffic forwarding is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! When I brought `eth0` down like this:

```
ifconfig eth0 down
```

traffic forwarding started working.

I think what was happening was the traffic was being forwarded from `wlan0` (the external wireless card) to `eth0`.